# How does an inline list override a property with no setter?

Tags: c#

I have an Item class that has a publicly accessible member NoSetter that does not contain a setter. The object does explicitly state a get, which retrieves a private readonly List object.

```
class Item
{
    private readonly List<string> emptyString;

    public Item()
    {
        this.emptyString = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> NoSetter
    {
        get { return this.emptyString; }
    }
}
```

When you create this object, you can't set NoSetter to a list, the compiler fails whenever you try.

```
List<string> goldenString = new List<string>();
goldenString.Add("Nope");
Item item = new Item()
{
    NoSetter = goldenString
    // or NoSetter = new List<string>();
};
```

However if you create the list inline you're able to set NoSetter.

```
Item item = new Item()
{
    NoSetter = { "But this still works" }
};

// Outputs: "But this still works"
Console.WriteLine(item.NoSetter.First<string>());
```

I expect that the NoSetter.Get method should be returning the readonly list emptyString , but instead returns the inlined NoSetter object.  What causes this in .net? Is it expected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your second piece of code isn't *setting* a new `List<string>`, it's just adding that value to it.

```
Item item = new Item()
{
    NoSetter = { "But this still works" }
};
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Item item = new Item();
item.NoSetter.Add("But this still works");
```

The `{...}` syntax when applied to a collection is known as a [Collection Initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).  Quoting from the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection class that implements IEnumerable. The element initializers can be a simple value, an expression or an object initializer. **By using a collection initializer you do not have to specify multiple calls to the Add method of the class in your source code; the compiler adds the calls.**

Comment: This `NoSetter = { "But this still works" }` doesn't look like syntax to `Add`, you are probably right, but is there any reference to it ?

Comment: I'm desperately searching... ;)

Comment: It makes more sense now.  The readonly emptyString isn't immutable just not assignable.

Comment: @CharlesMager `By using a collection initializer you do not have to specify multiple calls to the Add method of the class in your source code; the compiler adds the calls.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: @Andy, this is it, +1 to the answer

Comment: @Andy thanks, I'll add that to the answer.  It's a combination of collection initializer and object initializer.  The docs don't quite cover this specific situation, so you'd probably need to go to the spec to completely cover it.

Comment: more details in c# spec 7.6.10.3 Collection initializers